# Is composer's autoload_psr4.php needed after optimization?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, autoloader

After optimizing composer's autoloader (with `composer dumpautoload -o`), isn't it better to delete `autoload_psr4.php` to speed up autoloader as this file seems to be just something duplicate when all classes are in `autoload_classmap.php` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this file is generated by composer, why you need consider it? and autoload_psr4.php only contains psr defined files, autoload_classmap have other rules files like file and psr2.